# Laravel deny edit posts for users if current user not author

Tags: php, laravel

I have model `Post`. How I can deny edit post, if user is not author this post?

I know that I can show user only his posts with:

```
Auth::user()->posts
```

Because model user have:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

But every user can go with link: http://example.com/posts/6/edit

and edit stranger post. How I can prevent this?

My controller for edit post:

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $cats = Categories::all();
    return view('sites.edit', compact('cats'));
}
```

I created policy:

```
public function edit(User $user, Post $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

And I can show edit form post other users.. Why?

Comment: You may manually check post owner in edit method or check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization)

Comment: read current user with [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) and then see if it is the same as the author of the post. Do this in the edit() method. I'm not writing a detailed answer since it has been too long since I worked with laravel.

Comment: Take a look at [Laravel Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#gates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need its an authorization [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization)

Create a policy by running : `php artisan make:policy PostPolicy`

Then register the creted policy in service provider :

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
```

Once the policy has been registered, you may add methods for each action it authorizes. For example, let's define an update method on our PostPolicy which determines if a given User can update a given Post instance.

The update method will receive a `User` and a `Post` instance as its arguments, and should return `true or false` indicating whether the user is authorized to update the given Post. So, for this example, let's verify that the user's id matches the `user_id` on the post:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Post;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given post can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. not working this. I can show edit form does not matter

Comment: You still have to call `authorize` in the controller method for it to work.

Comment: @Dumitru you have to be very careful when implementing it and it works.

Comment: Please can you do example for method edit in controller? What I need do?

Answer (score 0):

In Your Controller :

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    if(Auth::user()->id==$post->user->id){
        $cats = Categories::all();
        return view('sites.edit', compact('cats'));
    }else{
        // redirect user to home page 
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```